# How to pass data to ajax with image and string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm having a problem of uploading a image with names in my database my code is working fine but it is only for image I can't add the name and other data in it

```
  var formdata = new FormData(this);

  formdata.append("movieprice", movieprice);
  formdata.append("movietitle", movietitle);
  formdata.append("moviecategory", moviecategory);
  formdata.append("upload", upload);
  formdata.append("image", image);
  var upload ="upload";

 $.ajax({
   url:"uploadmovie.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:formdata,
   contentType:false,
   processData:false,
   success:function(data){

     if (data === "YES"){
       alert(data)
       swal("Successfully Uploaded", "", "success")
       .then((value) => {
          window.location.reload();
       });
     }else{
       alert(data)
       swal("Error", "", "warning")
     }
  }
 });
}
```

Also this for the variables:

```
var movieprice = $('#movieprice').val();
var movietitle = $('#movietitle').val();
var moviecategory = $('#moviecategory').val();
```

How can I pass this value to ajax ?

here is the html for those looking for i didnt add the validation on javascript for the empty fields

```
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     <div class="w3-col m12 02">
        <div class="w3-rest w3-container w3-blue" style="width:100%;">
          <label id="label"><i class="fa fa-tag" style="font-size:24px;"> Movie Category</i></label>
        </div>
           <select id="moviecategory" name="moviecategory">
             <option>Romance</option>
             <option>Comedy</option>
             <option>Action</option>
             <option>Drama</option>
             <option>Horror</option>
             <option>Sci-Fi</option>
         </select>
     </div>

     <div class="w3-col m12 02">
        <div class="w3-rest w3-container w3-blue" style="width:100%;">
          <label id="label"><i class="fa fa-address-card" style="font-size:24px;"> Movie Title</i></label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="movietitle" id="movietitle">
     </div>

     <div class="w3-col m12 02">
        <div class="w3-rest w3-container w3-blue" style="width:100%;">
          <label id="label"><i class="fa fa-money" style="font-size:24px;"> Movie Price</i></label>
        </div>
        <input type="number" name="movieprice" id="movieprice">
     </div>

     <div class="w3-col m12 02">
        <div class="w3-rest w3-container w3-blue" style="width:100%;">
          <label id="label"><i class="fa fa-file" style="font-size:24px;">Movie Image</i></label>
        </div>
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image" /><br />
     </div>

     <footer class="w3-container">
       <button class="w3-right btn btn-danger" id="close" style="float: right; width:90px; margin-left:10px;">close</button>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="upload" id="upload" value="Upload Image" style="float: right; width:90px;">Add</button>
     </footer>
  </form>
```

and for the uploadmovie.php i got the error that image is undefined 
using this `$image = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];`

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target)) {
$target = "images/".basename($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
```

Comment: @IncredibleHat Slr, I already updated it

Answer (score 2):

You could add custom data into the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) instance using the method [`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) :

```
var movieprice = $('#movieprice').val();
var movietitle = $('#movietitle').val();
var moviecategory = $('#moviecategory').val();

// create FormData object
var formdata = new FormData(this);

// add custom data :
formdata.append("movieprice", movieprice);
formdata.append("movietitle", movietitle);
formdata.append("moviecategory", moviecategory);

// send data
$.ajax({
    url:"uploadmovie.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:formdata,
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    success:function(data){
        // ...
    }
});
```

The server-side will receive the data `"movieprice"`,`"movietitle"` and `"moviecategory"` in your `$_POST` array.

Comment: it proceeds to success but it doesnt add at database

Comment: Im using this  $movieprice = $_POST['$movieprice'];
   $movietitle = $_POST['$movietitle'];
   $moviecategory = $_POST['$moviecategory'];
  $file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));

Comment: @NeCat Yes to get the POST data. For the files, please see the documentation of [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php). You could also see the examples. For add to database, it hard to say here (many things to say). But you could ask a new question.